# Azure Blob Storage Virtual Directories using Shared Access Signatures

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I can't get shared access policies to work with virtual directories in blob storage. It works fine for containers. As far as I know, virtual directories are containers so SAS should work?

When I attempt to access a resource in a virtual directory using a SAS I get this response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.  RequestId:XXXXXXXX-000X-00XX-XXXX-XXXXXX000000 Time:2016-08-15T13:28:57.6925768Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2016-08-15T13:29:53Z /blob/xxxxxxxxxx/mycontainer 2015-12-11</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Example code to demonstrate:

```cs
public static async Task<string> GetFilePath()
{
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxx" );
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    var containerName = "mycontainer/myvd";     // remove /myvd and SAS will work fine
    var containerReference = blobClient.GetContainerReference( containerName );

    var blobName = "readme.txt";
    var blobReference = await containerReference.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync( blobName );

    var sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();

    sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes( 1 );
    sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

    var sasContainerToken = containerReference.GetSharedAccessSignature( sasConstraints );

    var path = $"{blobClient.BaseUri.ToString()}{containerName}/{blobName}{sasContainerToken}";

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this error is because `Shared Access Signatures` are only supported either at blob container level or blob level. In fact, in Azure Blob Storage there's no such thing as a `Virtual Directory`; it only supports 2-level hierarchy: Blob Container & Blob. A `Virtual Directory` is simply a prefix that you apply to a file (blob) name.

Based on this, I would recommend making following changes to your code:

```
var containerName = "mycontainer";     // remove /myvd and SAS will work fine
var containerReference = blobClient.GetContainerReference( containerName );

var blobName = "myvd/readme.txt"; //Your blob name is actually "myvd/readme.txt"
var blobReference = await containerReference.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync( blobName );
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect.

Comment: @Gaurav Is it at all possible to provide virtual directory level access , or we have to provide blob access itself? Actually I have a use case where different virtual directories can not be accessed by all , so I dint want to provide container level access . Please suggest.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I believe I saw an answer a few days ago where it was recommended that you use Azure Data Lake Gen 2 accounts (enabling Hierarchical support) and that way you can grant granular permissions at the folder level. With simple blob storage, it is just not possible.

Comment: Thank you @GauravMantri-AIS for the information . I can not use Data Lake as of now. Would you mind suggesting to what level we can restrict the access for storage? I read Container level, Blob Level etc.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi That's correct. There's one more level which is account level.

Comment: The order will be Account Level -> Container Level  -> Blob Level right ?

Comment: `The order will be Account Level -> Container Level -> Blob Level right ?` - That's correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214336/discussion-between-harmandeep-singh-kalsi-and-gaurav-mantri-ais).